# Vibrancy Effect on UIButton in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview

I have some visual effect views with blur and vibrancy in one of my view controllers. I have labels working correctly with vibrancy, but every time i try to add a UIButton to the view, the text appears to be transparent, and the background of the button appears to have vibrancy. I am looking for the effect the "Edit" button has in notification center. I have attached some photos for reference.

What I want:

[image]

What is happening:

[image]

If there is no way to accomplish this in IB, can it be done with code? I am using Swift.

**EDIT**

Now here is what happening, it appears with vibrancy, but the text is not dark:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried out setting `alpha` value of `color`? if you use plain color as background of `UIButton`.

Comment: Yes, changing the alpha does not help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can place your button above the view with vibrancy effect (view must have the same frame as your button).

Take a look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not able to do that. Interface builder will not let you add a view above or below the view with vibrancy.

Comment: Why not? Added screenshots for you. Visual effect view has the same frame as button.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your answer, thank you for uploading the screenshot, it helped. I will test it when I get home!

Comment: I tried this, but now it appears like a normal button without vibrancy. I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: EDIT: I played around with it a bit and I was able to get the vibrancy effect, but the text is not dark like in the example. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about your problem with text color. But I updated screenshots to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the edit with pictures. What are the text/background colors of your buttons?

Comment: And what are the background colors of the views and container views?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Thank you for all of the screenshots!