# keep interface builder constraints on button when adding to vibrancy

Tags: swift, constraints, uivibrancyeffect

I have a button I created and made constraints for in interface builder. However, now, I want to add it to a vibrancy effect.

So when I add it to the content subview when creating the vibrancy. The button losing all the constraints. Is there a way to keep the constraints from interface builder?

Using swift.

```
    vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(buttonOulet)
    visualEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)
```

Comment: didn't find answer to the above, but did find help in this post +2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820444/vibrancy-effect-on-uibutton-in-interface-builder?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, quick answer is once you start making a vibrancy view either by code or in interface builder the original constraints are deleted. By following the link in my comment above it helped me a lot creating a vibrancy view in IB and the constraints.