# Vibrancy Effect on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview

I asked this question a while back, but I seem to be having somewhat of the same issue, now with a UIImageView: [Vibrancy Effect on UIButton in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820444/vibrancy-effect-on-uibutton-in-interface-builder)

What I would like to do is replicate the effect seen in the iOS Photos app on the play icon when looking at a video thumbnail. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Example]

As you can see, there seems to be a nested UIVisualEffectView, one with an Extra Light Blur, and one with a Dark Blur and Vibrancy. However, when I try to implement this setup in interface builder I do not get the same result. The part I am struggling with is getting the play arrow to use vibrancy.

The only image I am using is the play arrow, and I have set its rendering mode to Template as the Apple docs say to do.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Clicking on play icon for me it is opening only image.

Comment: @Ramis I attached an image to show you the effect I want. I was just referencing the photos app in saying that the effect I want occurs when you look at videos in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Made a demo project at
 https://github.com/rishi420/VibrancyEffectTest

First I tried with ASCII character used for play. The character is "►". Set it as a button title. It works but not very beautiful.

Then I tried with image. The image has solid color for the middle triangle. Other areas are transparent. It would look like this: 
[image]

---

This is how it looks on white background. Simply hide the backgroundImageView in the sample project. I see gray color arrow, can not reproduce "*but in this sample project it is just white*".

For test, In the middle image there is a transparent (0.5) dark view behind the vibrancy effect view.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for making the sample project and everything! If you take a look at the iOS photos app, all of the play arrows seem to have a dark tint. How is this achieved as I see you are using Extra Light blur in your app?? I have tried changing the blur style to Dark, but that removes the blur altogether.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out with the darker button?

Comment: No. You could change the background image in the sample project. see if for a darker background, button looks ok.

Comment: I don't want to change the background image. I want this to work for all images and still be dark, like in the iOS photos app.

Comment: I could be wrong. But I don't see darker button for bright background videos.

Comment: For example, a white background in the photos app would produce a grey play button, but in this sample project it is just white. I believe the arrow does have a darker tint for all backgrounds in the photos app.

Comment: Sorry, it appears I had fiddled with some of the views and device settings before trying the white background and thats why I was getting the white play button. New example project helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: With iOS 9.3 there is no translucency in the bottom two buttons - the middle (image) is black.